# Make new instance of application open in current desktop

Tags: gnome, pop-os, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with Pop OS (Gnome-based) with multiple desktops. Currently, I have the following default behavior when I launch an application (either from the terminal or a desktop shortcut):

1. If no instance/window of the application is currently running, a new instance is created on my current desktop.
2. If the application is already running, the workspace shifts to the one where the application is.

Is there some configuration I can change, so that instead, if an instance of the application is already running, then either:

- a new instance is created in the current desktop
- the old instance is moved to the new desktop

or, if neither of these options are possible, is there a way to "pin" an application so that new instances by default open in a certain workspace?